# Need Help: Exponential Equations (Same bases)

Tags: exponentiation

$3^{n+2} + [3^{n+3} - 3^{n+1}] = ?$

How do we get the answer for this?

Do I just remove the bases and proceed to find the value of $n$ or do I use logarithms?

Comment: $$=3^{n+1}[3+3^2-1]=?$$

Comment: With what logic should you remove the basis ? o.o

Comment: Why is my question being down voted? Lol. I'm new here, sorry. Anyway, the answer is supposedly 3/8. It was multiple choice, the answer was given in the answer key but the solution was not.

Comment: I have no idea, I'm no math genius.

Comment: It is not possible to determine the value of $n$ unless we have an equation.

Comment: for what stands this here $$[..]$$?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Well, I guess it's just parenthesis. A remnant of the original post, where he had written $$$$ 3^(n+2)+[3^(n+3)-3^(n+1)]$$$$

Comment: factor this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have this here $$3^{n+2}+3^{n+3}-3^{n+1}=3^{n+1}(3+9-1)=11\cdot 3^{n+1}$$

Comment: Thanks, I got this answer as well :)

Comment: It can't be simplified to 33 ⋅ 3^n ?